# Bind SortedList<object, object>-Item to DataGridColumn in MVVM-application

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, sortedlist

in my MVVM-application I have a SortedList as a property in the model:

```
public SortedList<Geschäftsjahr, Stückzahl> IstStückzahlListe
{
    get
    {
        return istStückzahlListe;
    }
    set
    {
        if (istStückzahlListe == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        istStückzahlListe = value;
    }
}
```

And now, I want to bind a single item of this SortedList to a single DataGrid column. For this, I am creating for each KeyValuePair a DataGridColumn-Object with a certain binding:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<Geschäftsjahr, Stückzahl> kvp in IstStückzahlListe)
{
    cols.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { 
        Header = kvp.Key, 
        Binding = new Binding(String.Format("IstStückzahlListe[" + kvp.Key + "].Number")) 
    });
}
```

Besides, I think it's important to know, that a `Geschäftsjahr`-Object consists of two seperate years (f.e.: 2017/18) and the ToString()-Method returns the data in exactly this format.

Sadly, the DataGridColumn is empty...

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: "Sadly, the DataGridColumn is empty..." - That would suggest to me that the binding is not correct. In the Output window it should show warnings about the binding failing, you should check that output.

Comment: The output window shows the following error multiple times:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''ValueList' (HashCode=48701244)'. BindingExpression:Path=IstStückzahlListe.[2017/18].GeschäftsjahresWert; DataItem='Baugröße' (HashCode=66729601); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Comment: I think it has to do with the key, I use for the SortedList-access. But I don't know how the key should be instead.

Comment: Looks like the key is `null`. Try debugging and see what value it is returning.